# Syndicate Wars (PC): getting past EuroCorp space station

Tags: syndicate-wars

On the EuroCorp side, how do you get through the space station?  It seems impossible to beat because there seems to be a bomb planted somewhere that blows up the level, every time.

Comment: +1 because I was never able to beat that stupid space station level. I alway ran out of space or time to collect the bombs the zealots were holding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the walkthroughs on this website. That might help...

http://syndicate.lubie.org/swars/walkthrough/swars_leveurocorp_pc.php

this is the Orbital Station level

http://syndicate.lubie.org/swars/walkthrough/swars_lev088.php

> The self-destruct sequence is cleared as soon as you reach this last terminal.